# Add a new dimension to a Tensor, will modify its data?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using Python 3.7.7. and Tensorflow 2.1.0.

I have this piece of code:

```
class_prototype = tf.math.reduce_mean(support_set_embeddings, axis=0)

print("Embeddings type: ", type(support_set_embeddings))
print("Class prototype type: ", type(class_prototype))
print("Support set embeddings shape: ", support_set_embeddings.shape)
print("Class prototype shape: ", class_prototype.shape)
```

With this output:

```
Embeddings type:  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
Class prototype type:  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
Support set embeddings shape:  (5, 12, 12, 512)
Class prototype shape:  (12, 12, 512)
```

I get this shape `(12, 12, 512)`, but I want a Tensor with shape `(1, 12, 12, 512)`.

To get it, I did:

```
tf.expand_dims(class_prototype , axis=0)
```

But, will modify its data if I add a new dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding dimensions doesn't modify your data. It just changes the dept or dimensions of your data.

Eg:

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
x1 = tf.constant(np.array(range(1,9)))
x2 = tf.reshape(x1, (2,2,2))
x2
```

**Output:**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])>
```

Now if you use `expand_dims` it just adds another dimension to your data.

**Code:**

```
x3 = tf.expand_dims(x2, axis = 0)
x3
```

**Output:**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]],

        [[5, 6],
         [7, 8]]]])>
```

You can think of `expand_dims` as appending the array to an empty array.

You can achieve the same results by using the `reshape` function instead of `expand_dims` function.

**Code:**

```
x4 = tf.reshape(x1, (1,2,2,2))
x4
```

**Output:**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]],

        [[5, 6],
         [7, 8]]]])>
```

Comment: Thanks. Array dimensions is one thing that I don't understand. Well, I understand it until 3D array, if the array has more dimensions, I don't understand it. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The data is not modified.

`(N, 12, 12, 512)` means you have N elements with shape `(12, 12, 512)`.
For `N=1` this means you have 1 element of shape `(12, 12, 512)` which is therefore equivalent to `(1, 12, 12, 512)`.

Expanding the dimension further just continues this logic:

`(1,1,12,12,512)` means you have 1 element with 1 element which has shape `(12, 12, 512)`. So in the end we still have only 1 `3D` tensor.

Only for `N>1`, we end up with a different number of elements in the tensor, meaning we have modified the underlying data (e.g. by repeating the `3D` tensor).